# JQuery Mouseleave event for IE7

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, mouseleave

I am implementing a simple dropdown menu with code below:

```
<div id="submenu">
  <img id="1" src="..." />
  <img id="2" src="..." />
  <img id="3" src="..." />
</div>
```

the jquery code is:

```
$('#submenu').mouseleave(function(){
$('#submenu').slideup()
});
```

It works fine in Firefox but not IE. In IE, when the mouse leave the child element (image) and it will trigger mouseleave and submenu closed. I refer to JQuery doc and presume mouseleave will not have this issue. Can anyone please share your comment on this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with how the event is being attached to the dom - dom events triggered by a contained element may be bubbling out to the outer element. A workaround may be to test that the element is correct

```
$('#submenu').mouseleave(function(event){
    if($('#submenu')[0] == event.target){
        $('#submenu').slideup()
    }
});
```

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding <ul> and <li> for those images. But I don't know why that is the case.